# What kind of protection will be: PfSense as Tor Proxy

Tags: transparent-proxy

I will setup gateway machine with 2 NIC: `eth0` for WAN and `eth1` for LAN. On gateway machine I'll install [PfSense](http://pfsense.org) and setup Tor Proxy like for example here [How to Set Up a Tor Proxy Server on pfSense](http://skear.hubpages.com/hub/How-to-Set-Up-a-Tor-Proxy-Server-on-pfSense). Client machine will be Windows.

Is it similar to Whonix Gateway + Workstation?

What kinds of leaks are then possible?

How to improve this setup without changing its parts?

Answer (score 1):

Whonix provides a gateway and a workstation to reduce the risk of accidentally disclosing information out-of-band from the Gateway. In your setup, it appears you're just going to tunnel all traffic over the Tor network? If that's the case, you're at a heightend risk to accidentally send potentially identifying information through Tor on the same circuits that you're performing anonymous activity.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use IPTables on Linux box : the manual you've referred to is not so clear. You need to drop **ALL** UDP, but DNS-related UDP queries must be routed to your local DNS *server*, not Tor itself. After that - all the leaks are up to your client setup: for example, if you will enable it to access your GPS device, it will leak your location for sure, but it's not a problem of the router itself and Tor.